# Confusion over "does" and "do"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I saw this quote:

> What kind of education *does* your professors have?

but this sounds incorrect, and I have confusion as to whether the correct usage is:

> What kind of education *do* your college professors have?

Which one is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Or, "What kind of education does your college professor have?" But this really seems like a question for [ell.se].

Comment: Your instincts are right. In English nouns end in _-s_ in the plural; but verbs end in _-s_ in the singular.

Comment: I'm just wondering: why was this downvoted (twice)? It's an acceptable question with a clear question and a non-opinionated, hard answer. Right?

Comment: @jlam55555: probably because it is a very basic question, it is obviously an English language learner's question (and one that is not very interesting to most native speakers), and the general issue it deals with is addressed many times in resources for students of English, including many other websites and even many other questions on this website.

Comment: @jlam55555: In other words, there's little evidence of following the instructions given for "Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?" on the Help Page: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (" Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!")

Answer (score 2):

The subject *your professors* is unequivocally plural, so only *do* is grammatical here.

I'm not aware of any dialect of English in which *does* would be grammatical there: I conclude that this is either simply a mistake, or was written by somebody who is not a native English speaker.